# rcarousel add custom event

Tags: jquery-ui, carousel

I would like to use rcarousel jquery.
So far it works nicely. I have just a problem with the following: when the image of the carousel change, I would like to have the background image to change also. To do this, I should be able to catch the event triggered when the page is changed. Is there a way to do this??

I was thinking about overriding the method:

```
$("#ui-carousel-next").bind("click", function(e) {}
```

this would work for next/prev/page but not for automatic change.
any hints?

thank you,
colin

Answer (score 0):

The rcarousel plugin does give you the pageLoaded event:
http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/#options

```
$("#carousel").rcarousel({
    pageLoaded: pageLoaded
});

function pageLoaded(event, data) {
    //do something magical
}
```

In this way you can do whatever you need to on each pageLoaded event.